# Millitary Dissolvement

Tags: military

The military in my world makes no sense, as everyone works together. It is formed of three continents and a lot of islands. They all work together in unison, but some smaller islands are archaic. For example, most of the world has agreed on a conlang and is letting their "archaic" languages die away, whilst the small islands use their own language, and only the conlang in formal situations, such as cross-island bureaucracy.

I am wondering, what would the implications of a military that is either a skeleton (basically embers, with only next-to-nonexistent funding and is only there to be easily started up)  or non-existent be in this world?

Comment: What tech level is the world?  The answer is very different for ancient, medieval, or modern day tech.

Comment: It is a world slightly higher than us. They regard science as the pinnacle of modern life, and are constantly reforming life, like removing inconsistencies that develop in their conlang.

Answer (score 12):

For anything resembling a modern military, the implications of "*basically embers, with only next-to-nonexistent funding and is only there to be easily started up*" are, in one word, fatal, if a functioning military needs to be raised again to face an external threat.

- Infrastructure for training and supporting new servicemen (bases, depots, training facilities) has to be constructed from scratch.
- Quality of trained troops is drastically reduced because of the small number of experienced instructors.  For specialists, like pilots or naval engineering officers, even just the core training takes a couple of years.  And that's just for producing inexperienced personnel.
- Worse, it takes much more training and years of experience to produce a core of competent officers to lead servicemen and other officers.  Green troops + green officers = disaster.  As for general/flag officers, well, there simply will be none worthy of the rank.
- "*Generals always fight the last war.*" Without recent combat experience or updated equipment, the combat doctrine of the skeleton military is out of date for both using weapons built with current tech and gear and facing weapons and gear built with current tech.
- "*Plans are useless, but planning is essential.*"  Without built up organizations for global reconnaissance/intelligence gathering and analysis and organizations for war planning, there is no up-to-date playbook of high-level strategy that can be adapted to meet the current military crisis.
- "*Amateurs talk about tactics but professionals study logistics.*"  Procurement and logistics infrastructure for a large military has to be rebuilt from scratch.  Factories need to be created to build weapons and supplies, a logistics branch needs to be created to manage, store, and transport those supplies where they need to go.  For high tech weapons like missiles or large vehicles like tanks, aircraft, and ships, the factories take even longer to set up.
- R&D infrastructure for production of new weapons also has to be produced from scratch.  Military R&D is expensive so a largely unfunded skeleton military will be stuck with whatever equipment designs they had at the time of dissolution.

All of this is the work of decades to remedy.  Any competent opponent rolls right over these nations long before they have a chance to rebuild their own skeleton military back to any reasonable level of effectiveness.  In the end, they might as well simply not have it and save the money.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that having a millitary is 1/0 - Either agree on universal peace, or have a good millitary going.Of course,since my civilisation is ahead of us, they ahve agreed on peace, fighting their wars in sport.

Comment: Wouldn't most of your points work for any regular army? It seems that the same principles apply not only to the modern military but to other time periods as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Your country does not have a standing army.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_army

Many countries historically have raised an army when necessity mandated it.  The army could be formed of volunteer militia men who train together in additional to their regular jobs.  It could be made of conscripts compelled to serve or mercenaries hired to fight together with an aristocracy for whom military training is part of what it means to be a noble.

Standing armies were viewed with distrust by the Founding Fathers of the US.

> At the 1787 Constitutional Convention, Elbridge Gerry argued against
> a large standing army, comparing it, mischievously, to a standing
> penis: "An excellent assurance of domestic tranquility, but a
> dangerous temptation to foreign adventure."

Heh - I had not seen that quote before.  An army can take control of the country pretty easily and modern history is loaded with examples of exactly that.

---

Your country has no standing army.  Citizens practice militia training together in the manner that [Englishmen used to practice longbow after church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_longbow#Training) but they also practice other things they might be called on to do as a community - for example firefighting or flood control.  A sigh here for the modern demise of community endeavors and the societal solidarity they reinforce.

Your officers might be aristocracy or just educated persons who all have regular jobs but who received some military training as regard strategy, history etc. as part of secondary school.  These persons might practice together, or discuss these matters over drinks.

---

If you are going to be fighting a lot because you are an Empire and you fund your Empire thru conquest, you will want a standing army despite the expense and danger it presents.  The standing army will be undistracted by civilian concerns and better at what they do.  If you are not fighting a lot then your "embers" (good term!) makes a lot of sense.  They could call themselves Embers.

Comment: Thank you! What a brilliant idea! My world is formed of a better civilization than humans, who have agreed on universal peace. This seems like a brilliant to fight against a small uprising that is spreading across little islands (who tend to lag behind developments), whilst keeping costs low for a peacful world.

Comment: @56independent I'd be careful with casually-trained militias since phrases like "* the militia was seldom able to stand up alone to ... regulars*" and "* both sides struggled with barely trained, poorly-equipped, ill-disciplined and badly led armies*" appear often in their histories.  At best, you get light infantry out of them (aircraft/artillery/tanks and competent officers require more than just casual training), it's risky to deploy them remotely indefinitely (bad morale and bad public opinion), and they're also not trained in offensive operations or counterinsurgency to quell uprisings.

Comment: @56independent If you still want to do it though, it might be worth looking at the way the Swiss integrate their militia with their small standing military: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Armed_Forces

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of a military is the organized and controlled use of violence ("force") in pursuit of the state's *international* goals. That might mean war, or it might mean other force-related actions short of war.

- You might see stronger international verification and inspection systems to ensure that each state is not cheating.
- States might also retain a *generating force*, the camps and cadre and equipment and factories required to train and equip a *future* military.
- International disaster relief organizations would require a much more robust initial surge capability, since military airlift and sealift would no longer be available.
- Maritime police (Coast Guard) are often organized as a paramilitary. Depending upon the agreement, they might need to be restructured to less-resemble a military hierarchy while retaining their operational flexibility and capability.

The secondary purpose of a military is the pursuit of the state's *domestic* goals, which sometimes includes organized and controlled use of violence. Things like [crushing protests](https://www.nps.gov/articles/bonus-expeditionary-forces-march-on-washington.htm), disaster relief, support to law enforcement, fighting forest fires, building canals, [running National Parks](https://www.history.com/news/buffalo-soldiers-national-parks-rangers), or whatever else the state needs.

- In some states, political reform may be necessary if the military had a role in suppressing opposition.
- A new, flexible, rapid-response organization may be needed to handle emergencies and disasters.
- Many local police are organizaed as paramilitary. Like the Maritime Police, they might need to be reorganized.
- A new (or reorganized) form of state-level assistance to local police may be needed.
- Some states have mandatory conscription or national service for social or economic reasons (instead of military). The national service element must be enhanced.

Answer (score 2):

## A Different Kind of Army:

There are a wide variety of functions you can have an army perform that have little to do with fighting. An army without enemies can still remain viable, with only the officers receiving any formal training in warfare. Done right, your country may have a bigger army than when there WERE regular wars. And all those people under the army banner can receive basic training and military indoctrination. So in the event of a war, you are rapidly mobilizing a large force. They are more universally accepted in the public mind, because they aren't associated with violence anymore. I can't take credit for the idea, the basic framework was laid out in the series [The War With The Chtorr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Against_the_Chtorr), where the US loses a global war and is banned from having an army. The solution?

**An army by any other name is just as organized and disciplined.**

- **The Salvation Army**: You military could take up the functions of performing works of charity. In a society where the government is
  strong but social institutions are otherwise weak, the army musters
  the logistics of moving relief materials to disasters. So they keep the trucks, choppers, ships and transports to respond to disasters. Where there
  are rough neighborhoods, they show up and distribute food to the
  hungry and the homeless. What better recruiting tool than a sandwich?
- **The Military Police**: The army is the equivalent of the national guard, FBI, and Interpol. Every time there's a riot, the army shows up. Every time there's a murder, the army shows up. They are already the relief organization for disasters, so they are all ready the folks on the ground there.
- **The Coast Guard**: An extension of the military police Idea, you have the military maintain a fleet of ships and rescue helicopters to enforce maritime law, prevent piracy, and rescue idiots sailing into hurricanes.
- **The Army Corps Of Engineers**: When the government needs a construction project, they send in the army. Public construction is the purview of the military, who wants to keep up their skills at building defenses and having engineers available. They already do this in the US, building locks, dams, roads, etc.
- **The Civilian Conservation Corps**: The army is your employer of last resort. Lacking other social institutions, it's the welfare system of the able-bodied. During economic troubles, all those unemployed restless young people are drafted and put to work on those acts of charity, policing functions, and engineering projects.

Comment: Brilliant idea! I might as well add that the army split into two, a deep, defensive layer, who are made up of general people (think of the English Home Guard), whilst another group does exactly what you describe.

Comment: There's something to be said for having a large pool of already disciplined and fit recruits but none of those roles really prepare for combat, even the militarized police role (which is really about *avoiding* shooting at people).  IMO, even screening out those likely to crack under fire and then providing basic training will still only give you personnel a notch or two better than green troops in terms of combat effectiveness.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan I can't really dispute this, as there is no great way to get experience other than having wars. Since that option doesn't work, this is how I see the army on this world evolving for self preservation. Bureaucracies never die, they just mutate.